# How to get duration of youtube video from url in android

Tags: android, url, video, duration

i create list of video from youtube , and i display thumbnail, duration video , title , but when i want to get duration video error, i try like below :

```
public static String getDuration(String url){

        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(url);

        String time =  mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
        long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
        long hours = duration / 3600;
        long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
        long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

        return hours+":"+minutes;
    }
```

are there any step to get duration video from youtube or any video url ?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell like this  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF
            at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)